# mysql query which needs to do calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not so great with sql but I think what I want should be possible, I'm just not sure how to do it.

I have a site which allows users to list their youth hostel. Potential customers can then browse these hostels and place bookings.

Tables:

```
hostels
-------
max_guests

bookings
-------
hostel_id
check_in
check_out
guests
```

When users search the site I allow them to select a checkin date, a checkout date, a place name, and the number of guests. Note that each hostel has a maximum number of guests which they can accommodate, for example 20.

So say previously a booking has been made at a particular hostel for 8 people during the dates selected for the search, then I need to know that the maximum number of guests that particular hostel can accommodate between those dates is now 12, and it would only appear in searches for <= 12 guests.

Likewise if that hostel had a couple more bookings and was at it's maximum capacity, then it shouldn't turn up in the search at all.

At the moment I have a query which gets all the hostels but if there's any bookings for a hostel between the selected dates, then it's excluded from the results. I'd like to be able to get all the bookings for each hostel during the selected dates, count the numbers of guests booked in, and if that number subtracted from the max_guests of the hostel gives a result which is lower than the number of guests specified in the search, then exclude it from the results.

at the moment my query looks like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Hostel`.`id`, `Hostel`.*, `Hostel`.`id` 
FROM `hostelsdatabase`.`hostels` AS `Hostel` 
LEFT JOIN `hostelsdatabase`.`bookings` AS `bookings` ON (`bookings`.`hostel_id` = `Hostel`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `hostelsdatabase`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Hostel`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
WHERE ((`Hostel`.`address_one` LIKE '%london%') OR (`Hostel`.`address_two` LIKE '%london%') OR (`Hostel`.`city` LIKE '%london%')) 
AND `Hostel`.`maxguests` >= 4 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE `bookings`.`hostel_id` = `Hostel`.`id` AND NOT('2013-07-31' > `bookings`.`checkout` OR '2013-08-02' < `bookings`.`checkin`)) 
LIMIT 10
```

Can anyone tell me how I could modify that query to make it do what I need?

Comment: `"but if there's any bookings for a hostel between the selected dates, then it's excluded from the results."` - Do you know why that happens? If so, it shouldn't be hard to solve it.

Comment: Shouldn't the `hostels` table have a `hostel_id` or `id` field so the two tables have a common point? It's not in your description of the tables at the top of the post.

Comment: @devlshOne yeah, they both have id's but I just didn't include for brevity.

Comment: @goleztrol I know why it's happening, and I know how I'd sort the problem out with a pencil and paper, I just don't know whats the correct way to do that in sql. You shouldn't mock those less brainy than you :)

Comment: I didn't mean to mock you. I'm happy to help, otherwise I wouldn't be here. But this question sounded an awful lot like one of those many 'please do my work for me' questions, where you've got an existing query and don't even know how to read it. Just wanted to check.

Comment: :) no probs, I do know how to read my current query, I'm not sure how to do the maths I need in a query though. I'm pretty sure I've seen something similar some time before but I can't find a good example.

Comment: Has anyone any ideas about this?